# How to create a separate folder for backend controller in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, controller, backend, scaffolding

I am using cakephp in my project. I would like to create an backend panel so that admin can manage all type of data. Url may like this: `http://localhost/cake_project/admin/controller/action`. My question is can i create a separate controller folder for the backend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Prefix routing](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing) is probably what you need. To specify an alternate location for your controller files though you would have to use [App::build()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#App%3a%3abuild).

Answer (score 1):

You Have A define core.php in `Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin'));`

route.php file in put

```
Router::connect(
    "/{admin}/:controller",
    array('action' => 'index', 'prefix' => admin, admin => true)
);
```